# Codeigniter pagination offset issue

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

My view:

```
 <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

My controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_products_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
}

function index()
{   
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'products/index/';
    $config['total_rows']=$this->db->get('products')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page']=10;
    $config['num_links']=10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['products']= $this->admin_products_model->getProducts($config['per_page'],$page); 

    $this->load->view('products',$data);
}
```

My model:

```
function getProducts($limit,$offset)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->offset($offset);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $products[]=$row;       
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

As a result, when I click on the navigation links, the results ID's aren't ascending by groups of 10. For example 1st page: 85-95. 2nd page: 86-96. etc.
instead of 85-95, 96-106.

Comment: I can't understand why you are fetching num_rows, just ```return $query->result();``` instead. You are unnecessarily pushing core php in codeigniter.

Comment: Also you need to check that records exist or not - and also check ```$this->uri->segment(3)``` returns the number which you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller function :

```
public function index()
{
    $config ['base_url'] = base_url().'products/index/';
    $config ['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('product')->num_rows();
    $config ['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config ['per_page'] = 10;
    $config ['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = $config ['per_page']; // how many number of records on page
    $segment = $this->uri->segment ( 3 ); // from which index I have to count $page number of records

    $data['products']= $this->products_model->getProducts($page, $segment); 

    $this->load->view('products', $data);
}
```

Model function

```
public function getProducts($page, $segment)
{
    $this->db->select("prid");
    $this->db->limit($page, $segment);
    $query = $this->db->get('product');

    return $query->result();        
}
```

View :

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<br>
<br>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

You missed with `$page` and `$offset` thing in your code. You don't have to pass them separately in model, mention them in `$this->db->limit($page, $offset);`

Comment: Thank you so much. I also removed the:  $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE; line and it worked!

Comment: @marilena6 : please accept the answer if it worked for you